# Numbered hats, Warden and Maths

Tags: hat-guessing

You are one of 4 prisoners. Tomorrow will be a deciding day: the warden has told you and your cellmates that you can all go free, or all be executed, depending on how you answer tomorrow's challenge. He was kind enough to let you and your cellmates plan ahead a strategy. Tomorrow's challenge goes as follows:

> Each of you will be given a hat with a number. You will see your cellmates' hat numbers, but not your own. Each cellmate's hat will have a unique number (no duplicates). You don't know how small or big the numbers might be, but they will be integer numbers greater than 0. You will not be allowed to communicate when the hats are put in place.
>
> You will be given a sheet of paper in which you can write a number, and only a number - no punctuation or letters allowed. The warden will rewrite the number in his own handwriting, and remove zeroes to the left.
>
> Then, he will collect those numbers, scramble them and redistribute, such that no prisoner gets their own written number back. You may all go free if, and only if, you and your cellmates guess your own hat's number.

**Can you figure out a strategy which guarantees that each prisoner can guess their own hat's number?**

<sub>Note: I don't have an answer in mind. I'll keep trying to figure out this puzzle alongside.</sub>

Comment: Wasn't there a Khan Academy video like ths?

Comment: This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vJSNXPEwA

Comment: Can we pass notes while the warden is distracted by rewriting all the numbers?  ;)

Comment: I personally wouldn't risk being executed earlier by not being too careful :P

Comment: The statement "remove zeroes to the left" is ambiguous. My understanding based on the answers below is is that removing zeroes to the left means that a number like 02401 will be re-written as 2401 and not 00241 ..basically remove all the zeroes before the first non zero digit. Am I right ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure, it's perfectly doable.

> Encode all the other numbers you see in binary and separate them by the number 2. Once you get someone else's paper, find the number you *didn't* see: that is your hat. (You can also identify whose paper it is, too!)

Comment: Remember that the warden might remove zeroes to the left, but this strategy can still be salvaged ;)

Comment: @HugoBDesigner All positive binary numbers start with 1, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Right, oversight on my end. That is a great strategy, I might accept it in 24 hours. Nice job getting it so quickly!

Comment: Binary again?!! Can't you just use Octals and use 8 or 9 as separator?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Sure, why not? I was originally going to say "use base 9, and use 9 as a separator". But binary is more well-known, I think (and it shows how much freedom you have in this question).

Comment: Could even use base 1, just tallies of 1s with 0 separator _(may get tedious if somebody gets 100 as their number)_

Comment: @phflack yes, or even three tallies using different digits and no separator.

Comment: 24 hours? What's that? I only count in intervals of 4 days!

Answer (score 13):

> When you receive a paper, you can see the three hats of your three friends and their numbers $a,b,c$ ; let's say they are $3$, $4$ and $8$. 
>  Then the number you write down on the paper is $p_a*p_b*p_c$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number ($2,3,5,7,11$...). In our example, $p_3=5, p_4=7, p_8=19$, so you write $5*7*19=665$. 
>  Everyone proceeds in the same way. When you receive a paper with a number $N$, (say, $N=1045$), $N$ will have exactly three prime dividers (here, $5$, $11$ and $19$), leading you to three possible hat-numbers (here, $3$, $5$ and $8$). Two of those numbers you have seen by yourself, the third one is yours. 
>  In our example, your hat shows number $5$.

Everybody walks out free and happy.

> *Multiplying prime numbers is a classical way of conveying multiple pieces of information through a single integer.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit @HugoBDesigner I was getting crazy.

Comment: I go crazy with the spoilers tag too, hahah. Great strategy, by the way!

Comment: @Evargalo, if you want to make multi-line spoiler, add `<br>` to tell SE to make a line jump ;)  e.g: `>! line one <br> line two`

Comment: @Flying_whale Thx, that's what I just figured by checking how HugoBDesigner had corrected my answer. I hope I won't forget it before next time !

Comment: @Flying_whale: two spaces on the end of the line also allows linebreaks to happen.

Comment: @Evargalo: Do you mean "prime" rather than "primary"?

Comment: these could be huge numbers on each hat...are these guys Mathematicians?

Comment: @Chris oh yeah, bad translation. It sounded weird when I wrote it. And sure everybody is a mathematician, why would we be in jail in the first place otherwise?

Comment: man, imagine if someone has 1,000,000 as their hat number.

Comment: @votbear : Then you can use multiplication by $15,485,863$ ...

Comment: Let's say that I write , abcdef0gh on my paper (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h are all integers greater than 0). When the warden will receive it, then he will rearrange the number to ( 0abcdefgh) . Now, won't the person who will receive this rearranged number be faced with multiple possibilities ? What I mean is is that aren't there prime numbers such that, say, abc0defgh is also prime and abcdef0gh is also prime .

Comment: @Hemant The warden isn't supposed to rearrange the numbers, is he?

Comment: This is what the problem says, "The warden will rewrite the number in his own handwriting, and remove zeroes to the left."

Comment: @HemantAgarwal That means that if you write 000123345, the warden will only copy 123345, so you cannot trick him by adding useless zeroes in front of your number to pass any information.

Comment: "Multiplying prime numbers is a classical way of conveying multiple pieces of information through a single integer." Can you please give some other examples where multiplying prime numbers is used to convey multiple pieces of information or point to some article about this ?

Answer (score 11):

You're all making this much more complicated than it needs to be.  :)

> 1.  Count the maximum number of digits among the numbers you can see.
>  2. Starting with the largest number you can see, concatenate the numbers together, padding with `0`s at the start of each number if it has fewer digits, so that you write the same total amount of digits for each number.
>
> At this point, it's trivial to extract the original numbers again, simply by dividing the number into `n` equal lengths, where `n` is the number of hats you can see.  (In the case of the puzzle as stated, 3, but this same process works for any number of hats)

Let's take an example:

> Assume that there are four prisoners (including yourself), and you can see hats numbered `17`, `400`, and `17,400,145`.  You need to figure out what your own hat's number is.
>
> The number on the slip of paper handed to you says `174,001,450,000,040,000,000,145`.
>
> First, you count the digits:  That's 24 digits in total.  Divide by three and you know that each individual number is going to be eight digits long.  So taking the digits in sets of eight, you get back `17400145`, `00000400`, and `00000145`.  You can see hat number 17,400,145 and hat number 400, but you can't see a hat number 145, so you trivially know that that 145 must be your own hat's number.

Answer (score 8):

No maths required. Just write any message you want in Morse code, using 1 = dot, 2 = dash, 3 = space. An appropriate message might be something like, "Alice's number is 36473, Bob's number is 758254, Carol's number is 537242, oh and by the way the food here is terrible".

Answer (score 2):

This uses much less math than other options:

> Concatenate the observed numbers, then concatenate the numbers again but change the first digit of each number being concatenated (modifying the last digit also works).
>
>  Even if the numbers chosen were ambiguous when concatenated, such as repeating sequences or numbers of different length, you would write them in a given order: $ABC$, then again, modifying the first digit of each: $ABCabc$.
>
>  Example:
>
>  You see 12 121212 and 12121212. You write:
>
>  12121212121212124242121242121212. Whoever reads it divides it in half (this example doesn't require carrying, but if it did that fact would be obvious) 1212121212121212 and 4242121242121212 and sees where the 4's were added to correctly parse the first part: 12 121212 12121212, they see two of these numbers and know they are the third.
>
>  Another example: if you saw the numbers 3, 33 and 333, you would write down:
>  **333333553533**
>  Or something similar. Once splitting, the first half gives you the raw answer concatenated:
>  **333333**
>  Whereas the second half gives you the places to split it, based on where differences happen:
>  **5** - **5**3 - **5**33
>
>  This way, you can always tell the three numbers apart. Once receiving someone else's number, you can easily work out your number by excluding the numbers you can already see.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, mind giving an example?

Comment: Actually, I think your answer could be simplified further to a single, simple strategy. Should I write my own answer on it or edit yours?

Comment: How do you know whether a number is "tricky"? You don't know what's on your own hat when writing the note, so it can be tricky without you knowing.

Comment: @HugoBDesigner feel free to edit. @ Deusovi I think it can't be tricky unless there are 3 numbers of the same form, so everyone should to be able to see two before writing.

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a radical change, I just couldn't help but notice that your answer could be vastly simplified so that a single method could be used, regardless of whether numbers were "tricky" or not :P

Answer (score 2):

At your planning meeting,

> assign each of the four prisoners a number.  The four prisoners's numbers are $9$, $8$, $7$, and $6$.

Now on hat day:

> convert each hat number that you can see to binary ($0$'s and $1$'s), prepend the binary string with the corresponding prisoner's number ($9$, $8$, $7$, or $6$), and then put them all together (concatenate).

Example:

> Suppose you're prisoner $9$, and you see the following hats on the following prisoners: Prisoner $8$ wears hat $41$, Prisoner $7$ wears hat $74$, and Prisoner $6$ wears hat $11$.

Now:

> Convert the hat numbers to binary: Prisoner $8$ wears hat $10101$, Prisoner $7$ wears hat $1001010$, and Prisoner $6$ wears hat $1011$.

Write down the number

> $8101017100101061011$

When you get a number from someone else,

> Look for the part that starts with your number $9$, and convert the binary string that follows back to decimal.

If you'd like to do a little less writing,

> You could all agree to use base $6$ instead.  Or even base $9$, and number the prisoners as $9$, $99$, $999$, and $9999$.

Answer (score 1):

No math required.

Make this plan in advance, so everyone can do the same:

> 1: Write down all the numbers you see, one after another.
>  2: Encode the number of digits in each number as a string of ones and, say, sixes, and prepend it to the number string from step 1. Use the 1 to denote the first digit of a number.

For example, if the numbers you see are 42, 666 and 9000, write

> 161661666426669000

To guess your number,

> 1: Split the number string in half
>  2: Match the first half to the second half
>  3: Split the second half on the left side of each one in the first half
>  4: Match the numbers on hats to the list given by step 3. (you have probably already forgotten them, since the warden is going to use some really hard-to-remember numbers.), and

The one number you cannot see on another hat is your own number.

Comment: Why can't the strategy be to just concatenate the numbers that I see and write them on paper ? Taking your example, if I am seeing 42, 666 and 9000 then I will just write 426669000 on the paper . Can you give a case where this strategy will fail ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal : suppose you can see the numbers 1, 2 and 12, and you receive a paper with 12121, how would you know whether you are 21 (and the paper was written by the guy under hat 2) or 121 (and the paper was written by the girl under the hat 12) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Right the numbers that you see using trailing 0s as separators. the 4 numbers can then be decoded (since 0 is not a valid number) and your number is the number you did not see (since your guaranteed to not receive your own message).

Example numbers:

> 4 15 16 10

Encoding where you are 4:

> 15016010 or 15010016 etc.

Comment: This plan fails in the face of numbers with lots of internal zeros. For instance, if you see your fellow prisoners with numbers `1010101` (4 ones), `101010101` (5 ones) and `10101010101` (6 ones), and you get given a paper with `10101010101010101010101` (12 ones) written on it, you have no idea whether your number is `1`, `101`, or `10101` (since all you can do is count the ones, and `12 = 5+4+3 = 6+4+2 = 6+5+1`).

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you can remember all of the numbers that you have seen and the person who has this number.

Number each person in base 10, with leading zeroes so that each person has the same number of digits for their number (for instance, if there are 245 people, then person number 11 would have the number "011").

Write the sum of all the other numbers concatenated with the person number.

This will allow you to determine your own number.

How:

i)  Assume there are more than 100, but less than 1000 people.  Then you have 3 digits for the person number.  Assume you are person a (where a is this 3 digit number)

ii)  You add up all of the numbers that you see and get the answer X.

iii)  You write this on the paper concatenated with your number.  Since you are number a, this is Xa.

iv)  You receive a paper back, and use the last three digits, which we will call b to determine whose paper it is, and the remaining digits to know the sum, which we will call Y.  So the full number was Yb.

v) Assume that we remember what number was on b's head.  Call this number m.

vi) Subtract m from X, the original sum that you calculated and wrote down.  This gives the sum of all hats except your own hat and the hat of the person whose sheet you have, b.

vii)  The difference between Y, the sum of all hats except person b, and (X-m), the sum of all hats except yours and person b's, is the number on your hat.  This would be Y - (X-m).

This should work with any numbers as the numbers all had to be greater than 0, so the sum must be greater than 0.

Comment: If a person's number is "110", but prisoners A and B have hats "12345110110" and "11012345", wouldn't it be impossible to parse the numbers on the hats? Or do I understand your answer wrongly?

Comment: The person number is always three digits after the sum, (A+B+[your number])xyz with x,y,z each a digit in all cases. With your example numbers (taking your number arbitrarily as 12345110) the prisoner writes (12345110110+11012345+12345110) = 12368467565, then appends their personal number 110 => 1236867565110. You read this and see the ending 110 and know not to bother with the number on person 110's hat, subtract A and B from 12368467565 to get back to your number.

Comment: If a person's number is "110", then there are at least 110 prisoners.  Let us assume that there are less than 1000.  Let us further assume that the other prisoners, besides prisoners A and B, have a total sum of 1,000,000,000 on their hats.  We will assume that prisoner B is number "099."  Then, prisoner A would write the number `1011012345110` where the first 10 digits, `1,011,012,345,110 = 1,000,000,000 + 11,012,345` and the last three digits are prisoner A's number, "110."

Comment: Prisoner B would write the number `13345110110099` where the first 11 digits, `13,345,110,110 = 1,000,000,000 +  12,345,110,110` and the last three digits are prisoner B's number, `099`.  You then take `13,345,110,110 - (1,011,012,345,110 - 11,012,345) = 12,345,110,110` which is the number on your hat.

Comment: I think this answer could be simplified by solving for the question as given (four prisoners) and then once you have given that argument with examples then explain how to solve it for the general case. When the "how" starts with an assumption (there are more than 100 prisoners) whixh contradicts the facts given (ere are 4 prisoners) it doesnt make for a good explanation. That javing been said the technique seems to be good...